# How to resolve Node.js ES6 (ESM) Modules with the TypeScript Compiler (TSC). TSC doesn't emit the correct file-ext

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, configuration, es6-modules

I am trying to transpile my TypeScript project into JavaScript, however, something doesn't seem right. I configured the project to resolve as an ES6 Module (aka ESM), via the `"module":"ES6"` setting, but it doesn't solve the issue.

###### This is what my *`tsconfig.json`* configuration looks like:

```
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "es6",
      "target": "es6",
      "lib": ["es6"],
      "sourceMap": true,
    }
  }
```

#### Test Case Using a Pair of Modules:

I wrote a simple test-case senario using two modules.

1. The first module — ***`module1.ts`*** — only exports a constant, as shown below:

   - ```
       export const testText = "It works!";
     ```
2. The second module — ***`main.ts`*** — just imports the export from the first module:

   - ```
       import { testText } from 'module1';
       alert(testText);
     ```

The output file of the second module (or ***main.js***) is embedded in my ***`index.html`*** document, and I have added the type-attribute as `type="module"` to the `<script ...>` tag, as is shown below:

```
    <script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
```

When I test this with either **Firefox** (`dom.moduleScripts.enabled` is set in about:config) or **Chrome Canary** (Experimental Web Platform flag is set) it doesn't work.

The Typescript compiler seems to transpile the TS `import { testText } from 'module1';`-statement to the JS statement `import { testText } from 'module1';`. (Note: both are exactly the same)

The correct ES6 import-statement would be:
`import { testText } from 'module1.js';`
(Note the .js file extension)
If I manually add the file extension to the generated code, it works.

Did I do something wrong or does the Typescript `"module": "es6"` setting just not work correctly?
Is there a way to configure the tsc in such a way that .js file extensions are added to the generated import statements?

Comment: it's a known issue, reported as https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13422 and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577

Comment: I am solving same issue. Importing `*.js` file is nice work around, but then I had issues with refactoring in IDE (using CLion) and going to declaration, definition etc. So I switched back to importing without `*.js` extension and actually I am using SystemJS to transpile ES6 JavaScript (as temporary solution during development). I've found information about using TypeScript compiler [API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API). Thinking of "custom" build tool for this situation, but actually I am quite busy. If anyone has some ideas, notes or has something like t

Answer (score 23):

This is a [confusing design choice in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13422).

In the short term you can work around it by specifying the output file:

in `main.ts` specify the `.js` extension and path:

```
import { testText } from './module1.js';
alert(testText);
```

This will pick up `module.ts` correctly, but output with the `.js` extension included.

Note that you also need to prefix local files with `./` as 'bare' module names are reserved for future use.

Comment: really smart workaround for such bad TS bug ;) thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40878 is closed for "Working as intended". So it's a misfeature not a bug?

Comment: Good answer, just wanna mention that the `baseUrl` property got added to typescript v3.5 as a tsconfig option. If you set it to the root directory of all your typescript source files you can omit the `./` from local imports

Comment: @MuhammedAydogan - Unfortunately, the update is that the TypeScript team consider this "working as expected" and will not change the behavior.

Comment: Also if you miss out the .js suffix, the code still compiles so you'll get runtime failures, which isn't great to say the least.

Comment: If you are in a Node.js environment, I just wrote an ESM loader that intends to solve this issue: https://github.com/olalonde/tsc-module-loader

Comment: @olivierLalonde IMHO the worst thing the TS team ever did was consider Node to be their primary customer base instead of the JS that runs in browsers. ES modules work great in JS, but suck in TS because Node had already gone in a different direction. Your project looks like a good start for trying to get Node to support modern JS, but the TS support will still need a hack or some other post-process to be valid TS and actually output valid TC39 JS (i.e. full paths or import maps).

Answer (score 18):

> ###### NOTE FROM AUTHOR: *"The date that this answer was published is different than the date that the answer was originally created on. Due to changes in TypeScript, I have had to write a new answer twice. Because dates are extremely relevant in this post, I have included them in a couple places, in-case the answer gets stale. This will help readers know when I was referencing certain versions of any technologies that I have written about below."*

###### Originally Authored in December of 2021

---

#### The *"es-module-specifier"* Flag Fix for TS, ESM, NODE stacks

---

ESM was not an easy technology to incorporate into Node. And when it came to writing Node ES-Modules in the TypeScript language, well, that actually looked like, at a certain point in time, that it could never happen. IMO, it seemed like certain projects, didn't want to do what they, now have done, to support the Standard in the Node Back-end RTE. Anyhow, lets move on...

Initially when I answered this question I suggested that people who are experiencing this issue use the following flag:

###### [`node --es-module-specifier-resolution=node`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40878)

###### *(FYI: The solution came from the link attached to the snippet)*

The flag worked, or worked as the best solution up to this point *(or well up to TS 4.7 Nightly Release)*. **IT SHOULD BE NOTED** That depending on the environment, and the project, that you are working in, this will still be the best solution for now.

##### However, a Better Solution has been Made Available.

---

*At this Point in Time Much has Changed:*

During the Nightly releases of v4.6 TypeScript added support for new module & moduleResolution specifiers, which are *("obviously")* set in the `tsconfig.json`. They were released during the `v4.6` nightly builds, just a little while before v4.6 beta was released, and 4.7 became the nightly build. Now, `v4.7` is beta, and `v4.8` is the new nightly build (I mention all this version stuff, just to make sure your up to date).

###### These are the new specifiers/settings that TS has given to us

1. **`"module": "NodeNext"`**
2. **`"moduleResolution": "NodeNext"`**

###### [It has been Announced that v4.7 will include the new settings](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7-beta/)

The reason I say this is because, the new TSC-flags (aka tsconfig settings) were available in `v4.6`, *which, if you remember, I stated a couple paragraphs ago*, however; **TypeScript** decided not to release them in the current latest version *(`typescript@latest`)* version which is *`v4.6`*. So, they will be included in TypeScript officially, when `v4.7` is no longer in beta, and becomes the latest version.

They should always be used with `"esModuleInterop": true`, (unless somethings change on the **"Node.js"** side of things. The *"esModuleInterop"* setting eases support for ESM, and some of the node modules will need it to work properly with the new ESM import/export module system.

This is the ESM `tsconfig.*.json` configuration template, which I add as a starting point to each new project.

```
    "compilerOptions": {
        // Obviously you need to define your file-system
        "rootDir": "source",
        "outDir": "build", 

        // THE SETTINGS BELOW DEFINE FEATURE SUPPORT, MODULE SUPPORT, AND ES-SYNTAX SUPPORT
        "lib": ["ESNext"],
        "target": "ES2020",
        "module": "NodeNext",
        "moduleResolution": "NodeNext", 
        "esModuleInterop": true, // Eases ESM support
        "types": ["node"],
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    }
```

###### Written on: MAY 22nd, 2022 8:50am PST

---

##### Gaining Support for the *`module`* & *`moduleResolution`* Specifiers

---

So you have a couple different TS versions you can use to support the new configurations. You can either use **Beta** or **Nightly**. Below is a chart that demonstrates the 3 available versions. As of right now, `typescript@latest` is @ `v4.6`, and does not support the new configurations.

---

| TS RELEASE | VERSION | NPM COMMAND TO EXECUTE | HAS SUPPORT? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **TS Latest** | `v4.6` | `npm i -D typescript@latest` | ***NO*** |
| **TS Beta** | `v4.7` | `npm i -D typescript@beta` | ***YES*** |
| **TS Nightly** | `v4.8` | `npm i -D typescript@next` | ***YES*** |

---

##### Configure your Development Environment to use the Latest Ver

You need to configure your environment to use the new TypeScript version. I obviously cannot document ever editor's configuration, but **V.S. Code** seems to be the most common for **TypeScript**, and **V.S. 2022** uses a similar configuration.

In **VS Code**, you will add the following configuration to your workspace *`./.vscode/settings.json`* file.

```
  // "./.vscode/settings.json"
  { "typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib",}
```

##### Configuring Your Runtime Environment

*(Which, for this answer, is Node.js)*

---

***But why is this so? Why do I need to configure my RTE? Whats the deal??? Doesn't the RTE know everything?***

- No, the RTE doesn't just automatically know everything. It has to have some sort of instructions, or clues.

**But didn't we already Configure the **`tsconfig.json`** file?

- Yes, but that is for TypeScript, now we need to make sure node is ready for our TS configuration.

---

We need to tell node that we are going to be executing an ECMAScript Module, and not a CommonJS module. We can do this one of two different ways.

1. The first is to configure our `package.json` file using the *`package.json`* configuration file's "type" field.

```
    // @file "package.json" 

    {
        "name": "project-name",
        "version: "2.4.16",
        "type": "module", // <-- Lets env know this project is an ESM

        // the rest of your package.json file configuration...
    }
```

2. Alternatively, you can do the some thing as above, but by using the `--input-type "module"` flag
3. Lastly, you can do, what I prefer to do, and just create each file using the **ESM** file extensions. In js it is ***`.ejs`***, and in typescript it is ***`.ets`***.

###### For Example, your index file will be `index.ets` and TSC will emit `index.ejs`.

Lastly, its **IMPORTANT** that you understand how imports work when writing an **"ES-Module"**. I will list some notes, I think that will be the best format for this info.

1. You have to use JavaScript file extensions when importing files.
2. ESM imports are imported using **[URI's](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8820)**, and not by use of "possix filepaths". The opposite was true for CJS Modules.
3. [Special chars must be percent-encoded,](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#urls) such as # with %23 and ? with %3F.
4. TypeScript won't make you prepend the MimeType, but ESM uses prepended data types so its a best practice to do so.

For example, its a best practice to import from Node API's & Libraries using the following URI format:

```
import EventEmitter from 'node:events';

const eEmit = new EventEmitter();
```

Comment: Super underrated answer.  This flag is the best solution IMO - ensures you don't have to add the '.js' extension to all imports, it works with nodemon and supervisor AND it works with jest (I ran into a situation where I added the .js extension when running the server, but the .js extension broke my tests when running jest - this node flag solves this).

Comment: Note: moduleResolution: "nodenext" requires a nightly build, otherwise you'll get this error: `error TS4124: Compiler option 'module' of value 'nodenext' is unstable. Use nightly TypeScript to silence this error. Try updating with 'npm install -D typescript@next'.`. Upgrading TypeScript to 4.6 is not enough. More info: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47311#issuecomment-1004956269

Comment: Thank you @JohnnyOshika, feel free to edit those sort of details into answers when you notice them. I actually thought I included that.

Comment: Here is a post that covers using TypeScript ESM & Node together via the new TypeScript v4.7 module & moduleResolution values `NodeNext` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72213760/typescript-node-error-err-module-not-found-cannot-find-module/72215487#72215487