# Have typescript compiler add file extensions (.js) when building

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, typescript-compiler-api

In a typescript project I am working on, which runs both on node and in the browser (using the `type = 'module` in the html and package.json). However, it doesn't want to load files wihtout the .js extension at the end, and typescript is generating files that look like this:

```
import {foo, bar} from 'threeLetterWords';
```

This import fails both in node and in the browser, because it needs to find 'threeLetterWords.js'. How do I make the TSC auto add those .js extensions to the end of the imports?

My `tsconfig.json':

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./Build",
    "target": "ES6",
    
  }
}
```

And my file structure:

```
root  
  |___Build  
  |     |__(the root directory except for the build folder)  
  |  
  |__Public  
  |    |__scripts
  |    |     |__main.js  
  |    |     |__threeLetterWords.js  
  |    |__index.html
  |
  |__Server Logic
  |     |__threeLetterWordsServer.js
  |
  |__app.js
  |__package.json
  |__tsconfig.json
```

I have seen [Typescript compiler is forgetting to add file extensions to ES6 module imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979976/typescript-compiler-is-forgetting-to-add-file-extensions-to-es6-module-imports) , but that question was asked 3 years ago, and was vscode auto imports are extension-less, so I would have to change a lot (100+) by hand.

Has any progress been made, and if so what to do to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appending .js extension on relative import statements during Typescript compilation (ES6 modules)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619058/appending-js-extension-on-relative-import-statements-during-typescript-compilat)

Answer (score 1):

`threeLetterWords.js` and `threeLetterWords` are two different modules. The string `.js` has absolutely no magic meaning whatsoever in a module URI.

If you want to use the module `threeLetterWords` you have to tell TypeScript to use the module `threeLetterWords`. If you want to use the module `threeLetterWords.js` you have to tell TypeScript to use the module `threeLetterWords.js`.

TypeScript will not, ever, change the module name that you told it to use. I have a project that *depends* on TypeScript not changing the module name because I am using the Node module loader to resolve the module to either a native extension, CommonJS module, or JSON Module.