# Typescript/Node Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, typescript

#### Converting Project form *CJS* to *ESM*

I am attempting to convert my current TypeScript-Node project from ESM to CJS, however, I keep getting the error below

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module` 'redacted/dist/config/datadog' 
imported from /redacted/dist/app.js
```

###### This is what the import looks like in **`app.ts`:**

```
    import './config/datadog';
```

###### And this is what it looks like for **`app.js`**

```
  import './config/datadog';
```

###### Here is  my datadog.ts document

datadog.ts

```
import tracer from 'dd-trace';
tracer.init({
    logInjection: true,
    profiling: true,
    appsec: true
});

export default tracer;
```

Here is the full printout of the error I am recieving when I execute the app via `~/$ node dist/app.js`.

```
> node dist/app.js

node:internal/errors:465
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'redacted/dist/config/datadog' imported from /redacted/dist/app.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:405:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:966:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1176:11)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:605:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:318:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:80:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:78:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v18.0.0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It works fine When running using ts-node

```
node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --loader ts-node/esm app.ts --project tsconfig.json
```

###### I have configured my `tsconfig.json` file like this:

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2020",
        "module": "ES2020",
        "lib": ["ES2020"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
      }
    }
```

Comment: Does `dist/config/datadog.js` exist?

Comment: @quentin yes, dist/config/datadog.js is the same as datadog.ts

Comment: @Quentin Its his module resolution setting

Comment: The answer below will get you going. You will need `typescript@next` so you can resolve modules using ESM import statments with TypeScript in the node runtime. That requires the TS v4.7 tsconfig.json setting `NodeNext`, rather than `ES2020`.

Comment: maybe you can use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ebx to make things more simple and compatible

Answer (score 13):

##### Your need to use TypeScript v4.7 which is currently the TS-Next Version

---

Once you upgrade to `typescript@next` which can be done by executing the command `~/$ npm install -D typescript@next`, you will need to make the changes below to your `tsconfig.json` file.

```
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "ESNext" /* ESNext includes new Level-4 features that were
               recently added to the ECMA-262 JS spec */
     ],

    "module": "NodeNext",/* (1 of 2) TS v4.7 settings you need 
                            to change */

    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext", /* This is the one that will 
                                    specifically solve the error you're 
                                    getting. Without the internal changes
                                    made by this, your project will not
                                    resolve modules correctly. */

    "esModuleInterop": true, /* This is properly configured. FYI you cannot 
                                change this, it must be set to true. */
                                

    /* 
      THE REST OF THE SETTINGS DO NOT AFFECT THE MODULE TYPE OR HOW TSC 
      RESOLVES OTHER MODULES */

    "target": "ES2021",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
  }
}
```

### To Summarize

You must set the `tsconfig.json` keys `module` and `moduleResolution` as they are shown below.

1. `moduleResolution: "NodeNext"
2. `module: "NodeNext"`

##### You will need TypeScript v4.7

---

Personally I keep a global property, so below I show the command for the global install, but all you really need is to add it to your `node_modules` dir it as a dependency for your current project.

1. ##### `~$ sudo npm i -g typescript@next // Global Install`
2. ##### `~$ npm i -D typescript@next      // Add as a Project Dependency`

I can't help with ever IDE in existance, but if you use VSCode, use the following configuration so your project uses the ver v4.7.

Then you need to set the following configuration

```
"typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib",
```

#### `package.json`

You also need to [enable ESM in for Node.](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/esm.html#enabling). To do this you need to add the following to your `package.json`

```
/** @file "package.json" */

{
    "type": "module"
}
```

**...OR YOU CAN** use the **dot MTS (`.mts`)** file extension  for all of your files. There are advantages to both, but discussing the advantages is beyond the scope of this answer.

That should be it. It sounds hard but its actually easy once you have done it before.

---

##### For another helpful source:

[The answer at this **LINK** covers this same subject with a bit more detail.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979976/typescript-compiler-is-forgetting-to-add-file-extensions-to-es6-module-imports/70682797#70682797) **I really suggest you check it out.**

Comment: This covers the files automatically being inserted with `.js` extensions, which is needed for **ESM** ~ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979976/typescript-compiler-is-forgetting-to-add-file-extensions-to-es6-module-imports/70682797#70682797

Comment: Using 4.7 which is stable now, but the option changes specified don't seem to help :(

Comment: thank you - "moduleResolution": "nodenext" is what i needed.

you are a gentleman and a scholar

Comment: Using typescript 5.0.3 these settings do not seem to help. My guess is something changed. Can you please update the answer?

Answer (score 2):

#### From July 2023

I haven't tried updating my typescript to the `ts-next` version, but this solution worked for me for **Typescript v5.1**:

Simply add `.js` to the end of the filename on the import statements, as explained [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41887#issuecomment-741902030).

*Example*:

```bash
# Folder structure

app/
  controller/
    mymodule.ts
  index.ts
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

```json
// package.json
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module", // keep the module keyword
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  ...
```

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "ES2020",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "./app"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

```
// index.ts

import userController from './controller/users.js'
userController.foo();
```

```
// mymodule.ts

const foo = async () => {
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More insight:

Importing './env' only works in CJS.

Importing './env.mjs' is required in ESM.

```
Relative import paths need explicit file extensions in EcmaScript imports when '--moduleResolution' is 'node16' or 'nodenext'. Did you mean './env.mjs'?ts(2835)
```

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/#esm-nodejs